# transformation not applying on all svg g elements

Tags: svg

I want both images and rectangle to move , but only the first image and rectangle moves on applying transformation to "g" . Following is the code:

```html
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="cursor: move;">
    <image style="pointer-events: none;" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(1) translate(0)" x="526" y="154" width="84" height="48" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="image-path" />
    <rect visibility="hidden" style="cursor: move;" fill="none" pointer-events="all" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" x="526" y="154" width="84" height="48" />
    <image id="warningImage" x="482" y="182" width="20" height="16" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="image-path" />
</g>
```

The secong image is added to the g element programmatically using javascript.And the above is the dom structure available through developer tool after adding the secong image.
Can anyone tell me what fix is required?

Answer (score 0):

You are applying your transformation to your first `image` rather than to the `g`. If you want to transform the group and all its contents you will have to apply it to the group:

```svg
    <svg width="800" height="800">
        <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(1) translate(50,50)" style="cursor: move;">

            <image style="pointer-events: none;" stroke-width="1" x="526" y="154" width="84" height="48" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="image-path" />

            <rect visibility="auto" style="cursor: move;" fill="blue" pointer-events="all" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" x="526" y="154" width="84" height="48" />

            <image id="warningImage" x="482" y="182" width="20" height="16" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="image-path" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```